# How to disable automatic file upload on django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, model, frameworks

Hi I have a column named foto, I use this colum to store the path from my firebase storage so I do not need django storage but every time that I upload my file django generates a new file.

```
from django.db import models
from users.models import User

class Empleado(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    fecha_contratacion = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    curp = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)
    rfc = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    foto = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='fotos/')
```

I have a django rest framework serializer too, where is my code uploading the file to my django project?

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Empleado
from django.core import serializers as django_serializers
from users.serializers import UserSerializer, User
from .firebase import Firebase
    
    class EmpleadoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        """
        Currently unused in preference of the below.
        """
        fecha_contratacion = serializers.DateField()
        fecha_nacimiento = serializers.DateField()
        curp = serializers.CharField(required=True)
        rfc = serializers.CharField(required=True)
        telefono = serializers.CharField(required=True)
        user = UserSerializer(required=False)
        foto = serializers.ImageField(required=False)
    
        class Meta:
            model = Empleado
            fields = ('foto','user_id','user','fecha_contratacion','fecha_nacimiento','curp','rfc','telefono')
    
        def create(self, validated_data):
            """
            """
            user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
            user = UserSerializer.create(UserSerializer(), validated_data=user_data)
            empleado = Empleado.objects.create(user=user,**validated_data)
            return empleado
    
        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            if 'user' in validated_data:
                user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
                user = User.objects.get(id=instance.user_id)
                user = UserSerializer.update(UserSerializer(), user, validated_data=user_data)
            
            instance.fecha_contratacion = validated_data.get('fecha_contratacion', instance.fecha_contratacion)
            instance.fecha_nacimiento = validated_data.get('fecha_nacimiento', instance.fecha_nacimiento)
            instance.curp = validated_data.get('curp', instance.curp)
            instance.rfc = validated_data.get('rfc', instance.rfc)
            instance.telefono = validated_data.get('telefono', instance.telefono)
    
            if 'foto' in validated_data:
                instance.foto = validated_data.get('foto', instance.foto)
                instance.save()
                firebase = Firebase()
                firebase.upload(instance.foto)
            else: 
                instance.save()
            
            return instance
```

Answer (score 0):

> where is my code uploading the file to my Django project?

This shouldn't come with your settings.py, but it's safe to add these:

```py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),
]

FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tmp')
```

- The media root setting is just the file path to the directory that holds user-uploaded files.
- Staticfiles_dirs is the place where the uploaded files will be stored in your local machine.
- Temp_dir is a directory that holds partial uploads (some parts of a file may get through before the others).

As a matter of fact, in the code I provided above, 'media' and 'tmp' are all swappable for wherever you wish to store your files.

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/)

> store the path from my firebase storage but every time that I upload my file django generates a new file

Django never generates a new file. The file that appears in your file system is the file that you uploaded. If you are a client, you won't saw this as all the files you uploaded goes to your host one way or another.

You can't just store the path because what should be done if the file is moved or removed?

Comment: Well I upload client files in another server so I dont need django for this, how to stop django from saving this files?

Comment: You change the filefield to an urlfield. Upon saving/editing the model, you enter the link to your file on the other server instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think your file is being created at time of create, so you just need to unset the value, please correct me if this is not the case

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        """
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user_data.pop('foto')
        user = UserSerializer.create(UserSerializer(), validated_data=user_data)
        empleado = Empleado.objects.create(user=user,**validated_data)
        return empleado
```