# Why Django copies all images, which I use for creating of the model instances

Tags: python, django, image, copy

I have a model **'Book'**. It has a field **'image'**. Whenever I add a new instance on the admin panel, Django copies this image in a **'media'** folder. Why does it do it? Can I turn off this function?

Comment: Hey I found similar problem here, I think this answers it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63094576/how-to-disable-automatic-file-upload-on-django

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is part of the ImageField or FileField behavior.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#filefield

If you want just to change the storage location you can do that

If you do not want a unique picture for each book but a shared one you should create a foreign key to another model "picture" holding the picture in Imagefield. Then you only upload once.